# Django form cleaning acting strangely

Tags: python, django

I am overwriting clean method but when I do it like this:

```
def clean(self):
    if "post_update_password" in self.data:
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        old_password = self.cleaned_data['old_password']
        new_password1 = self.cleaned_data['new_password1']
        new_password2 = self.cleaned_data['new_password2']

    return super().clean()
```

It returns this: `{'old_password': 'Password,1.', 'new_password1': 'a'}` 
which means that I am unable to get that new_password2 value.

And when I change my clean method like this:

```
def clean_new_password2(self):
    if "post_update_password" in self.data:
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        old_password = self.cleaned_data['old_password']
        new_password1 = self.cleaned_data['new_password1']
        new_password2 = self.cleaned_data['new_password2']

    return super().clean()
```

It magicaly works and returns:

```
{'old_password': 'Password,1.', 'new_password1': 'PAssssad', 'new_password2': 'a'}
```

I really don't understand what is happening. I know how to bypass this issue but I am really curious where is the problem.
Thanks for any reply

Comment: You call the `super().clean()` *not* `clean_new_password2` in the function, so it returns a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Writing *clean()* and *clean_fieldname()* methods covers two very different needs.
The former lets you validate the value of a given field data, independently from others. The later allows you to validate your form by taking into account several fields value. So it's normal that the outcome of writing your "validation code" in either the first or second method is different.

Have you tried to follow [Django documentation about this subject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)?

As you will see in this doc, calling super.clean() at the end of a field validation method does not make much sense as it will be called anyway during the whole validation process. This method (for example *clean_new_password_2()*) should be constructed as follows:

```
def clean_new_password2(self):
    old_value = self.cleaned_data['new_password_2']
    new_value = ...
    return new_value # this is the value you want for this field
```

From what I understand from your use case, your code should be:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    ... # Do here the validation stuff you want to do with your field values
    # and if you changed the values of ones of the field in cleaned_data, do as follows:
    return cleaned_data # you can even return whatever you want
    # If you changed nothing, you don't need a return statement
```